# How to set 1000 threads which needs to completed in 1 minute(60 sec) by using stepping thread group in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am having a requirement to perform a load testing for api's with 1000 request per minute. i have setup a stepping thread group as displayed below :

[image: 1]

- In above image you can see that i have configured the parameters as 20 threads per second ,so it will take 50 seconds to reach 1000 threads. but still graph shows 2 min and 31 sec to completed the 1000 request.so please help me to set it.

Please help me to configure it properly , my exact requirement is as displayed below :

1) 1000 threads
2) In 1 minute it needs to be completed.

Comment: A thousand threads all competing for the same computer resources is not really a good idea. First try to create a *single* thread and see how many requests per minute it can make on its own. Then create two threads, three, etc. until you have reached your goal of 1000 requests per minute. I'll bet that it will happen way before you have a thousand threads.

Comment: Thanks , but then should is need to use remote server and masterslave concept ?

Answer (score 0):

Change stepping thread group settings to hold 60 seconds 1000 threads:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1000 threads (virtual users) will produce 1000 requests in one minute only under specific condition: **response time must be 16.6 milliseconds**.

- If response time will be higher - JMeter will execute less requests
- If response time will be lower - JMeter will execute more requests

If you want JMeter to conduct the load at rate of 1000 requests per minute it's better to consider [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) combination

Throughput Shaping Timer configuration:

[image]

Concurrency Thread Group configuration:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T, thanks for the response.

Can you please write a configuration  as i am not able to view the image. it will be very help full if you provide me both thread group configuration here.